# An exception was raised while creating "Request"; no instance returned

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

When running the following commands:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento set:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

I get this error:

```
An exception was raised while creating "Request"; no instance returned
```

Comment: did you check the permission for generated and the var-folders?

Comment: it's caused by vesrion of php 7.3 i just delete this version and installed the appropriate extensions for 7.1

Comment: I need help in other subject : I have to delete some products and add others in the grid of products and i want to show specific products of category. So i need to override the grid in BO but when it comes to di. I don't know what to put as main table because i have different type of products (configurable virtual and simple] and every type had its tables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I try with this on my php7.2 magento2 '2.3.1, sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2 Sucess.

Answer (score 54):

Please change the **PHP version** of your terminal using

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
```

Change PHP version according to your **Magento** version. E.g. for **Up to Magento 2.3.2 PHP 7.2** is highest version

Answer (score 34):

Most of the time downgrading PHP is not feasible. So until we get fix from Magento here is a work around

> As of PHP 7.3, a warning will be thrown when continue is used within a
>   switch without a numeric argument. Ref: php/php-src@04e3523

So changing core files solve the issue.

1. Change **`continue`** to **`continue 2`** in vendor/zendframework/zend-stdlib/src/ArrayObject.php @ line 426.
2. Change **`continue`** to **`continue 2`** in vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Pdf/FileParser/Font/OpenType.php @ line 901.
3. Change **`continue`** to **`continue 2`** in vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Pdf/FileParser/Font/OpenType.php @ line 920.
4. Change **`continue`** to **`continue 2`** in vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Pdf/FileParser/Font/OpenType.php @ line 932.

Now try doing `bin/magento setup:upgrade`.
It will work ..!!

Comment: automation 
https://gist.github.com/0m3r/ac8b8c83edead75a476c0657ade52a7c

Comment: Thanks @abdul it helps me

Answer (score 2):

This issue happens due to PHP changes and now need to use "continue 2" withing "switch" case.

You need to changes the vendor\zendframework\zend-stdlib\src\ArrayObject.php at line #426

```
continue
```

TO

```
continue 2
```