# An exception was raised while creating "Request"; no instance returned magento2 command error

Tags: magento2, command

I am trying to execute magento command on my terminal but getting this error "An exception was raised while creating "Request"; no instance returned"

I tried running all these commands
 php bin/magento module:status
 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 php bin/magento cache:flush

But all giving this error

Answer (score 1):

This error might be due to incompatibility with PHP 7.3

> As of PHP 7.3, a warning will be thrown when continue is used within a
>   switch without a numeric argument. Ref: php/php-src@04e3523

Please see my old answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/278143/77673

Thanks